# In php how do you say if ($x == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4) {do function} without repeating code many times?

Tags: php

Im not great in php and I could do with a little help. I want to say something like

```
if ($x == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4) {do function}
```

but the only way i know how to do that is to go

```
if (($x == '1') or ($x == '2')) or...
```

which seems a long way of doing it. Is there a better way I am missing, like

```
if ($x == 1,2,3,4) {do}
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4)

if(in_array($x, $array)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like the method of least code and I will try it now!

Comment: Nest the array for speed ---- if (in_array($x,(array(1,2,3,4)))){

Answer (score 5):

```
switch ($x) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        // do
    break;
}
```

Or you can use the `in_array()` function creating an array such as `$a = array(1,2,3,4);` and then do `if (in_array($x, $a))`.

If you are concerned about space, you can also use the shortcut:

```
if (in_array($x, array(1,2,3,4))) { /* do */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of expected values and then use function in_array().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1):

If it's a range, you could do:

```
if ($x >= 1 && $x <= 4) { }
```

You could also construct an array and check if the number is in that array.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $data = array(1,2,3,4);
    if(in_array($x, $data)){
        // execute function
    }  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above ideas are good.  I am going to show another way, that is not better, but is different.

You can store comparations in variables, to use later or combine. This helps readability, and make complex expresions easy to create and read. It obviusly remove any repetition.

```
$is_number = ($str=="one" or $str=="two" or $str=="tree");
$is_english = ($str=="one" or $str=="horse");
$is_french = ($str=="baguette" or $str=="amie");
$is_fun = $is_french or $is_english;

if($is_french and !$is_number){ ... }
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for that - both interesting and useful. Not as good as a simple array for my current needs, but I will try it in the future as I am sure it will come in handy!